# More expensive than others

Tags: word-usage, word-order, comparison, comparative-constructions

Let's imagine I have some boats with different prices. I am going to be selling them soon. I have gotten a person to buy one of them and he approached the boat I am selling for the highest price. Can I say something like:

*I am selling it for more expensive than others*

*I am selling it more expensive than others*

*I am selling it for more expensive than all*

*I am selling it more expensive than all*

*I am selling it for a more expensive price than others*

or how can it be said correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Most of these suggestions are ungrammatical and even the last one, which is grammatical, is unnatural.

As @geoyeo says in their answer, **expensive** is a adjective, so it must modify a noun.  Furthermore, **expensive** means "high-priced," so it sounds unnatural to say "a more expensive price" since that means "a more high-priced price," which sounds redundant.  The adjective **expensive** is generally applied to the object being sold (i.e., the boat), not to the price of the object.

A more natural way of saying what you're trying to express could be:

> This boat is **more expensive** than the others I am selling.

Or even better:

> This is **the most expensive** boat that I am selling.

Note that using the superlative **most** contrasts the boat against all of the others in the category without needing to mention them.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, the last statement is grammatically correct, as expensive is an adjective, therefore a noun would have to come after. However, many phrase the term differently, some examples are in the other answers. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I feel like it should be formulated this way; "I am selling it at a higher rate compared to the others". I hope this helps!

Comment: It isn't a "rate" that would be either how fast you are selling, or the interest that you are charging. It doesn't mean the price.